# fleqn and vertical space

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, vertical-spacing

I'm writing my master thesis according to this template:

https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/1407993358863322/Thesis_template_LaTeX_v7.zip

I've tried using the `fleqn` option right at the beginning of the **Thesis.tex** file, but I get huge amounts of vertical space around equations. I looked up some of the possible problems, but in the end I really can't understand what's causing this.

Can someone help?

Thanks!

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Set the document class
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % <<<<< Linux
\usepackage[english]{babel} % <<<<< English

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\def\FontLn{% 16 pt normal
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontLb{% 16 pt bold
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontMn{% 14 pt normal
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontMb{% 14 pt bold
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontSn{% 12 pt normal
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}


\usepackage{geometry}   
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % AMS mathematical facilities for LaTeX.
\usepackage{amsthm}   % Typesetting theorems (AMS style).
\usepackage{amsfonts} % 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfigmat}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1}} % column aligned by the point separator '.'
\newcolumntype{e}{D{E}{E}{-1}} % column aligned by the exponent 'E'
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
%
% Group variables according to their symbol type
%
\RequirePackage{ifthen} 
\ifthenelse{\equal{\languagename}{english}}%
{ % English
    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
            \item[\textbf{Roman symbols}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
                \item[\textbf{Greek symbols}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
                    \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
                        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{}}}}}%
}{% Portuguese
    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
            \item[\textbf{Simbolos romanos}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
                \item[\textbf{Simbolos gregos}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
                    \item[\textbf{Subscritos}]}{%
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
                        \item[\textbf{Sobrescritos}]}{}}}}}%
}%

\usepackage[number=none]{glossary}
\setglossary{gloskip={}}
\makeglossary
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} % enhance documents that are to be
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Begin Document                                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Set plain page style (no headers, footer with centered page number)
\pagestyle{plain}

% Set roman numbering (i,ii,...) before the start of chapters
\pagenumbering{roman}

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Equations}
\label{subsection:equations}

Equations can be inserted in different ways.

The simplest way is in a separate line like this

\begin{equation}
\frac{{\rm d} q_{ijk}}{{\rm d} t} + {\cal R}_{ijk}({\bf q}) = 0 \,.
\label{eq:ode}
\end{equation}

If the equation is to be embedded in the text. One can do it like this ${\partial {\cal R}}/{\partial {\bf q}}=0$.

It may also be split in different lines like this

\begin{eqnarray}
{\rm Minimize}   && Y({\bf \alpha},{\bf q}({\bf \alpha}))            \nonumber           \\
{\rm w.r.t.}     && {\bf \alpha} \,,                                 \label{eq:minimize} \\
{\rm subject~to} && {\cal R}({\bf \alpha},{\bf q}({\bf \alpha})) = 0 \nonumber           \\
&&       C ({\bf \alpha},{\bf q}({\bf \alpha})) = 0 \,. \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

It is also possible to use subequations. Equations~\ref{eq:continuity}, \ref{eq:momentum} and \ref{eq:energy} form the Naver--Stokes equations~\ref{eq:NavierStokes}.

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left( \rho u_j \right) = 0 \,,
    \label{eq:continuity}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho u_i \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \rho u_i u_j + p \delta_{ij} - \tau_{ji} \right) = 0, \quad i=1,2,3 \,,
    \label{eq:momentum}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho E \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \rho E u_j + p u_j - u_i \tau_{ij} + q_j \right) = 0 \,.
    \label{eq:energy}
    \end{equation}
    \label{eq:NavierStokes}%
\end{subequations}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get directly into your question.

Comment: And if you try the `\raggedbottom`  or  `\allowdisplaybreaks` directives in your preamble?

Comment: @leandriis There are too many nested files, it's best to just download the zip file and run Thesis.tex with the added fleqn in the document class options.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added a mashup of the files in the zip archive, the vertical spacing remains.

Comment: thanks.........

Comment: You know `\rm` hasn't been defined by default in latex since 1994? Odd to see it in a new document:-)

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File `glossary.sty' not found.`  Also never have a blank line above a display math, that _always_ introduces spurious white lines, with or without fleqn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
> 10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 5.0pt.
l.82 \showthe\abovedisplayskip
                              
? 
> 0.0pt plus 3.0pt.
l.83 \showthe\abovedisplayshortskip
```

so as it's never possible to use the short skips with `fleqn` there will be 10pt extra above `equation`, however the spacing is wrong anyway as there should never be a blank line before a display math, as it always generates a spurious white empty line of a paragraph before the equation. Similarly don't use one equation after another, use a multi-line display such as `gather`

output with and without fleqn

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside,
%fleqn
]{report}

% not required in recent latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   % <<<<< Linux
\usepackage[english]{babel} % <<<<< English

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}

\def\FontLn{% 16 pt normal
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontLb{% 16 pt bold
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}\fontsize{16pt}{16pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontMn{% 14 pt normal
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontMb{% 14 pt bold
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{b}{n}\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont}
\def\FontSn{% 12 pt normal
    \usefont{T1}{phv}{m}{n}\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont}


\usepackage{geometry}   
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % AMS mathematical facilities for LaTeX.
\usepackage{amsthm}   % Typesetting theorems (AMS style).
\usepackage{amsfonts} % 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfigmat}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1}} % column aligned by the point separator '.'
\newcolumntype{e}{D{E}{E}{-1}} % column aligned by the exponent 'E'
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
%
% Group variables according to their symbol type
%
\RequirePackage{ifthen} 
\ifthenelse{\equal{\languagename}{english}}%
{ % English
    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
            \item[\textbf{Roman symbols}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
                \item[\textbf{Greek symbols}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
                    \item[\textbf{Subscripts}]}{%
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
                        \item[\textbf{Superscripts}]}{}}}}}%
}{% Portuguese
    \renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{R}}{%
            \item[\textbf{Simbolos romanos}]}{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{%
                \item[\textbf{Simbolos gregos}]}{%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{%
                    \item[\textbf{Subscritos}]}{%
                    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{T}}{%
                        \item[\textbf{Sobrescritos}]}{}}}}}%
}%

% not in texlive\usepackage[number=none]{glossary}
%\setglossary{gloskip={}}
%\makeglossary
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} % enhance documents that are to be
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%     Begin Document                                                   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% Set plain page style (no headers, footer with centered page number)
\pagestyle{plain}

% Set roman numbering (i,ii,...) before the start of chapters
\pagenumbering{roman}

%\showthe\abovedisplayskip
%\showthe\abovedisplayshortskip

% -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Equations}
\label{subsection:equations}

Equations can be inserted in different ways.

The simplest way is in a separate line like this
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} q_{ijk}}{\mathrm{d} t} + {\cal R}_{ijk}(\mathbf{q}) = 0 \,.
\label{eq:ode}
\end{equation}

If the equation is to be embedded in the text. One can do it like this ${\partial {\cal R}}/{\partial \mathbf{q}}=0$.

It may also be split in different lines like this
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathrm{Minimize}   && Y(\mathbf{\alpha},\mathbf{q}(\mathbf{\alpha}))            \nonumber           \\
\mathrm{w.r.t.}     && \mathbf{\alpha} \,,                                 \label{eq:minimize} \\
\mathrm{subject~to} && {\cal R}(\mathbf{\alpha},\mathbf{q}(\mathbf{\alpha})) = 0 \nonumber           \\
&&       C (\mathbf{\alpha},\mathbf{q}(\mathbf{\alpha})) = 0 \,. \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}

It is also possible to use subequations. Equations~\ref{eq:continuity}, \ref{eq:momentum} and \ref{eq:energy} form the Naver--Stokes equations~\ref{eq:NavierStokes}.

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{gather}
    \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left( \rho u_j \right) = 0 \,,
    \label{eq:continuity}
\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho u_i \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \rho u_i u_j + p \delta_{ij} - \tau_{ji} \right) = 0, \quad i=1,2,3 \,,
    \label{eq:momentum}
\\
    \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left( \rho E \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \rho E u_j + p u_j - u_i \tau_{ij} + q_j \right) = 0 \,.
    \label{eq:energy}
    \end{gather}
    \label{eq:NavierStokes}%
\end{subequations}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, David! I didn't know about the white lines before display math, I appreciate that. Looks like I was using subequations inappropriately as well. I don't have any problems now :)  Regarding the \abovedisplayskip parameter, should I keep it?